# SOSL does not find gmail domain in emails for Site Guest User

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl, digital-experience

When running a SOSL query as the Site Guest User in an Experience Site, I am unable to retrieve any results if I return more than one object at a time while the search query is 'gmail.com'

As an example, the following does not return any records:

```
String emailId = 'testemail@gmail.com'
String emailDomain = 'gmail.com'

List<List<sObject>> testQuery = [FIND :emailDomain IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Name WHERE (Email = :emailId OR SecondaryEmail__c = :emailId)), Lead (Id, Email, Name, Account__c WHERE Email = :emailId)];
```

While, this returns a single Contact record, as expected:

```
String emailId = 'testemail@gmail.com'
String emailDomain = 'gmail.com'

List<List<sObject>> testQuery = [FIND :emailDomain IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact (Name WHERE (Email = :emailId OR SecondaryEmail__c = :emailId))];
```

- If I run the first query as any non Site Guest User it returns
  results across both objects.
- If I alter emailDomain to virtually any non 'gmail.com' value it works as expected.
- The objects I query largely do not seem to matter(the final full query in the environment includes User, Contact, Account, and Lead)

I have also verified in multiple ways that the Site Guest User does indeed have access to the Objects and Fields in question (queried via SOQL, verified in the profile UI & sharing settings, can query the records if the domain is not 'gmail.com')

Comment: Welcome! There's been quite a few [security updates](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_networks_guest_sharing_security_alert.htm) to Guest Users so I suspect it might be related - are there any guest sharing rules?

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, but I have verified that the Guest User has access to the records in question via querying them directly with SOQL, reviewing sharing/object security/FLS. Also, I wouldn't expect one of these queries to work if this was access related, right?

Comment: How many contacts and leads do you have? SOSL can behave differently when querying against one object versus multiple ([documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_limits.htm) and [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77110/sosl-query-returns-only-250-records-even-if-there-are-more-than-2000-records-pr))